# Definir variables con nombres recurrentes en Compass (SASS)

Tags: css, variables, sass, scss

Necesito definir **100 variables** que están compuestas de un prefijo y el número tal que así:

```
$negro_trans1 : rgba(0,0,0,.01);
$negro_trans2 : rgba(0,0,0,.02);
$negro_trans3 : rgba(0,0,0,.03);
$negro_trans4 : rgba(0,0,0,.04);
$negro_trans5 : rgba(0,0,0,.05);
$negro_trans6 : rgba(0,0,0,.06);
$negro_trans7 : rgba(0,0,0,.07);
...
```

Necesito crear un **@for** para no tener que escribir uno a uno la definición de las variables. Para mí tendría sentido hacer algo así:

```
@for $i from 1 through 99{
    $alpha : $i/100;
    $negro_trans#{$i}' : rgba(0,0,0,$alpha);
}
```

**¡Pero no funciona!**
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer esta declaración de variables?

Comment: ¿Que quieres hacer, usar Sass para crear variables de Sass? No creo que eso sea posible

Comment: Yo tampoco por lo que he podido encontrar al buscar pero ¿no sería bonito crear variables dinámicamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca he tenido la necesidad de tener 100 variables declaradas asi, sin embargo, si tuviese necesidad de algo como lo mencionas, lo solucionaría con una función de sass, algo tipo:

```
@function negro-trans($nivel){
    @return rgba(0,0,0,$nivel/100);
}
```

Y lo usaría de esta manera:

```
.mi-clase {
    color: negro-trans(1);
}
```

Comment: ¡Me gusta! ¡Muchas gracias por la solución!